# Issue with null pointer check in process builder

Tags: formula, process-builder

can anyone help out me to in the following formula? I need to put a null check for the opportunity whenever the contract is created and not for edited. I have chosen 'Formula evaluates to true' and developed the below formula but it is not working.

```
AND(
AND(ISNEW(),
NOT(ISNULL([Contract].Opportunity__C))),
OR(
ISPICKVAL([Contract].Opportunity__C.Deal_Category__c, "aaa"),
ISPICKVAL([Contract].Opportunity__C.Deal_Category__c, "bbb"),
ISPICKVAL([Contract].Opportunity__C.Deal_Category__c, "ccc")
),
OR(
[Contract].RecordType.Name = "yyy",
[Contract].RecordType.Name= "zzz"
)
)
```

Comment: can you make Opportunity__C to Opportunity__c and try? and use Isblank instead of isnull.

Comment: Hi Kumar thank you for helping me.. I have already tried with ISBLANK() but no luck.. is it case sensitive for process builder?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% which parts you need, but it seems sensible to guard against null Deal_Category__c or RecordType:

```
AND(
    AND(ISNEW(),
        NOT(ISNULL([Contract].Opportunity__c)),
        NOT(ISNULL([Contract].Opportunity__c.Deal_Category__c)),
        NOT(ISNULL([Contract].RecordType))
    ),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL([Contract].Opportunity__c.Deal_Category__c, "aaa"),
        ISPICKVAL([Contract].Opportunity__c.Deal_Category__c, "bbb"),
        ISPICKVAL([Contract].Opportunity__c.Deal_Category__c, "ccc")
    ),
    OR(
        [Contract].RecordType.Name = "yyy",
        [Contract].RecordType.Name= "zzz"
    )
)
```